# I have some questions about Steam

Tags: steam, pc

1. Do I download the games to hard drive?
2. How much is the service?
3. Does Steam OS make the experience better or what?

Comment: I think you should start out on Steam's [About page](http://store.steampowered.com/about/).

Comment: Hi Luis, Welcome to Arqade! Just a heads up, generally we prefer one question per 'question' asked here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, games are downloaded to your hard drive before you can play them. You can select the location where the games are to be downloaded and stored [by specifying a custom game library path](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=7710-TDLC-0426).
2. Steam by itself is free to sign-up and use, however most games, to the exception of free-to-play ones, are paid and requires you to buy them. You can pay [trough multiple means](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=8360-WEJC-2625), including Credit Card and PayPal. You can also [set up a Steam Wallet account](http://store.steampowered.com/steamaccount/addfunds/) to store funds dedicated to Steam purchases.
3. Steam OS is still a bit of an experiment for the upcoming Steam Boxes, and for dedicated Steam gaming computers. It doesn't make the experience particularly better as it is more of a Debian Linux distribution with Steam starting in Big Picture mode upon startup -- this implies the games you want to play must be running on Linux (indicated by the OS icons above the "Play" / "Buy" button on the game's Steam page), however their number is increasing and [many are already available](http://store.steampowered.com/browse/linux). For some games (mostly Source engine-based), there can even be a performance increase as they are optimized for the platform (more specifically, using OpenGL) and as there is minimal desktop interface overhead compared to Windows.